# Selenium + Capybara: run Chrome with parameters in Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, capybara

While being run in a container, Chrome can throw exception, something about PIDs and totally not related to the question at hand.

To solve this, you have to run chrome like:

```
google-chrome --no-sandbox --user-data-dir /root
```

**Question is**, how do i pass the `--no-sandbox --user-data-dir /root` part to Capybara and/or Selenium.

This is how i register my driver

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  require 'selenium/webdriver'
  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path =     ENV['CHROMEDRIVER_EXECUTABLE']
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
   app,
   :browser => :chrome,
   desired_capabilities: {
      "chromeOptions" => {
       "args" => %w{ window-size=1920,1080 }
     }
    }
  )
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add more options to `args`

```
"args" => %w{ window-size=1920,1080 no-sandbox user-data-dir=/root }
```